# Save image to record

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe3

I'm storing some information to my Access database, one parameter is a BLOB field, in this case an image, loaded into a Timage.

I'm using this code to save it:

```
var
AStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(AStream);
AStream.Position := 0;
if Adotable1.Active then
begin
  Adotable1.Edit;
  TBlobField(Adotable1.FieldByName('Termograma')).LoadFromStream(AStream);
  Adotable1.Post;
end;
  finally
    AStream.Free;

adotable1.Append;
adotable1['Data']:= datetimepicker1.Date;
adotable1['Temax']:= edit4.Text;
adotable1['Temin']:= edit5.Text;
adotable1['Descrição da Posição']:= memo1.Text;
adotable1['Comentários']:= memo2.Text;
adotable1.Post;
```

But I also have other information I'm storing by clicking in the same button like the "append" part.

What happens is that when I press the save button, this information does not get stored in the same ID on the database.

How do I correct this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're editing the current record, saving the image to it, appending a new record, and saving the rest of the info to that new record. I think you intend to add an entire new record, add the image and data to that new one, and then save those changes.

Try this instead:

```
var
  AStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  if not AdoTable1.Active then
    AdoTable1.Open;

  Adotable1.Append;

  AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(AStream);
    AStream.Position := 0;
    TBlobField(Adotable1.FieldByName('Termograma')).LoadFromStream(AStream);
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;

  adotable1['Data']:= datetimepicker1.Date;
  adotable1['Temax']:= edit4.Text;
  adotable1['Temin']:= edit5.Text;
  adotable1['Descrição da Posição']:= memo1.Text;
  adotable1['Comentários']:= memo2.Text;
  adotable1.Post;
end;
```

Comment: I'm saving these images as .Jpeg, but I keep getting this "bitmap image  is not valid" error. I'm loading the image like this:     if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute(Self.Handle) then
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);

Comment: That's a totally separate question from this one, and should be asked as one. :-) This one is about saving the image to the database, and it has been answered.